# Вычисление расхождения массивов

Tags: php

```
            //есть 2 массива $result и $currentData 
                   foreach ($result as $myKey => $res){
        echo $myKey."\n";
        $this->stdout($myKey,Console::FG_YELLOW);
              if ($res == $currentData){
                  echo "Данные равны";
              }else {
              return array_diff_assoc($res, $currentData);`
             }
            }//почему мне возвращяет только первый ключик и все?
               return [
'auction.edit.all.documents' => [
    'evaluationCriteria' => 'documentType.auction.evaluationCriteria',
    'contractProforma' => 'documentType.auction.contractProforma',
    'technicalSpecifications' => 'documentType.auction.technicalSpecifications',
    'notice' => 'documentType.auction.notice',
    'illustration' => 'documentType.auction.illustration',
    'clarifications' => 'documentType.auction.clarifications',  
],
'auction.copy.all.documents' => [
    'evaluationCriteria' => 'documentType.auction.evaluationCriteria',
    'contractProforma' => 'documentType.auction.contractProforma',
    'technicalSpecifications' => 'documentType.auction.technicalSpecifications',
    'notice' => 'documentType.auction.notice',
    'illustration' => 'documentType.auction.illustration',  
],
//при создании
'auction.documents' => [
    'evaluationCriteria' => 'documentType.auction.evaluationCriteria',
    'contractProforma' => 'documentType.auction.contractProforma',
    'technicalSpecifications' => 'documentType.auction.technicalSpecifications',
    'notice' => 'documentType.auction.notice',
    'illustration' => 'documentType.auction.illustration',               
],

'auction.edit.documents' => [
    'clarifications' => 'documentType.auction.clarifications',
],
'auction.all.documents' => [
    'evaluationCriteria' => 'documentType.auction.evaluationCriteria',
    'contractProforma' => 'documentType.auction.contractProforma',
    'technicalSpecifications' => 'documentType.auction.technicalSpecifications',
    'notice' => 'documentType.auction.notice',
    'illustration' => 'documentType.auction.illustration',
    'clarifications' => 'documentType.auction.clarifications',
],

   $result = [
        'auction.edit.all.documents' => ($arr['auction']),
        'auction.copy.all.documents' =>  $this->array_remove($arr['auction'],['clarifications']),
        'auction.documents' =>  $this->array_remove($arr['auction'],['clarifications']),
        'auction.edit.documents' => $this->array_remove( $arr['auction']),
        'auction.all.documents' => $this->array_remove( $arr['auction']),
        'bid.all.documents' =>  ($arr['bid']),
        'bid.create.documents' =>  $this->array_remove($arr['bid'],['auctionProtocol']),
        'bid.user.documents' =>  $this->array_remove($arr['bid'],['auctionProtocol']),
        'auction.cancelled.documents' =>  ($arr['cancellation']),
        'award.all.documents' =>  ($arr['award']),
        'award.verification.unsuccessful.documents' => $this->array_remove( $arr['award'],['auctionProtocol']),
        'award.pending.active.documents' =>  $this->array_remove($arr['award'],['rejectionProtocol','act']),
        'award.bidder.pending.documents' =>  $this->array_filter($arr['award'],['auctionProtocol','digitalSignature']),
        'award.unsuccessful.documents' =>   $this->array_remove( $arr['award'],['auctionProtocol']),
        'contract.active.documents' =>  $arr['contract'],
        'contract.cancelled.documents' => $this->array_remove( $arr['award'],['auctionProtocol']),
        'contract.all.documents' =>  ($arr['contract']),
    ];
```

Comment: вы там раз в 5 часов по вопросу задавать будете одному и тому же. сказано вам приведите пример исходных данных и жалаемоего результатта. Конкретный пример что у вас лежит в массивах. а не названия переменных.

Comment: жмите [edit] и вставьте форматированный код туда.

Comment: @teran поправил

Comment: @teran назад приходит только 'auction.edit.all.documents'